# Create link to executable in parent directory (..)

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

Create the following directories:

```
parent/child
```

Navigate to child and create a file named `child` (this is an executable file in my case, not sure if that makes a difference).

I need to create two "link to executable" links in the parent. I had assumed that this would work:

```
ln -sf ./child ../child1
ln -sf ./child ../child2
```

But that creates a "link to folder" (./child) in the parent directory.

If I change it to:

```
ln -sf -t.. ./child child1
ln -sf -t.. ./child child2
```

I get an error, "ln: '../child': cannot overwrite directory".

If I do it from the parent directory (which I cannot do, this is part of a Makefile recipe):

```
ln -sf ./child/child ./child1
ln -sf ./child/child ./child2
```

It works.

Note that I cannot alter the names of any directories or files.

How do I create the links when the current directory is the child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the first argument, TARGET, is *relative* to the location of the link. In other words, you're creating links called **parent/child1** and **parent/child2** which both link to **./child**.  From the perspective of those links, **./child** is the directory.  You need to link to **./child/child**.  Or better yet, create an absolute link:

```
ln -sf /full/path/to/parent/child/child ../child1
ln -sf /full/path/to/parent/child/child ../child2
```

Comment: But that would require hard-coding the full/path/to/parent in the Makefile. I just tried `ln -sf ../child/child ../child1` which produced a broken link. Is there no way to do it without the full path?

Comment: Use **./child/child** as I suggested, rather than **../child/child**, as you said you did. But using full paths in a Makefile should be easy anyway. I do it _all the time_ in my own Makefiles.

Comment: You're right, I had access to a $(ROOTDIR) variable which allowed me to do it with the full path and not a hard-coded path. Thank you.